# Javascript Only the first button submits to Ajax form despite different Ids

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Other users have had similar problems about when they're looping rows of buttons but it's always because they accidentally reused the same Id or value. I'm experiencing the same problem, but all of my buttons are unique.

> AJAX request

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#friendadd").submit(function(){
                    alert("checkpoint");
                    $.ajax({
                        type:"POST",
                        url:"getuser.php"
                    });
            })
        });
    </script>
```

> PHP and form

```
            <form id="friendadd">
    <?php
        for($i=0; $i<$ctk->rowCount(); $i++){
            echo "<img src='".$ctk_values[$i][6]."' alt='Blank' style='width:64px;height:64px'>";//PP, Later add clickable profile
            echo "<th rowspan='3'>Attributes</th>";
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][0]."</tr>";//UN
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][1]."</tr>";//UL
            echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][5]."</tr>";//UA
    ?>
                <input type="submit" id="friend<?php echo $i;?>"><!--pass in this.value-->
            </form>
    <?php

                }//Ends for loop
            }
        }
    ?>
```

> Explanation: When I type in a username into the search box, it returns me three different users named rikesh1, rikesh2, and rikesh3. Each of them have a button next to them, with values friend0, friend1, friend2, respectively. When I click on the friend0 button, it successfully calls and updates the database. When I click the friend1 button, nothing happens. This is different from other users in that my buttons have unique Ids. Thanks for any and all help, I think this is a very fixable problem but after searching Stack, I'm still not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        <form id="friendadd">
<?php
    for($i=0; $i<$ctk->rowCount(); $i++){
        echo "<img src='".$ctk_values[$i][6]."' alt='Blank' style='width:64px;height:64px'>";//PP, Later add clickable profile
        echo "<th rowspan='3'>Attributes</th>";
        echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][0]."</tr>";//UN
        echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][1]."</tr>";//UL
        echo "<tr>  ".$ctk_values[$i][5]."</tr>";//UA
?>
            <input type="submit" id="friend<?php echo $i;?>"><!--pass in this.value-->
<?php

            }//Ends for loop
?>
        </form>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Use this code instead.

The other one ends the form tag at the first loop.

Comment: giving you an upvote for spotting that subtle, hard-to-find 'bug'

Comment: Very fast logical answer. Thank you very much!